# Can't find Multibit wallet file after closing wallet

Tags: wallet, multibit

I closed a wallet in the 0.5.x version of Multibit for Mac.  Now I can't seem to open it. When I use Open Wallet in File the file name comes up, as does my home library, but I can't figure out where it is stored. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac the wallets are stored by default in the user data area:

/Users/"user name"/Library/Application Data/MultiBit

The default wallet file name is "multibit.wallet".

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSx 10.9.1 (Mavericks)

`/Users/username/Library/Application Support/MultiBit/multibit.wallet`

Remeber to replace "username" with your own.