# Closed a wallet in Multibit mac and cant find it from application support

Tags: wallet, multibit

First time installed Multibit for mac and had my bitcoins transfered there. I had the software and wallet open for 2-3 days and decided to close the wallet. After closing i couldnt find the wallet in the application support folder. There was nothing related to multibit in that folder. Ive been trying to search .wallet files from the Finder but it comes up empty. Are my bitcoins gone for good?

Comment: related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/cant-find-multibit-wallet-file-after-closing-wallet

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you looked in the right folder? The path should be: `/User/your username/Application Support/Multibit/xxxx.wallet`.

I didn't find my wallet because I made the misstake to looked directly under root: `/Library/Application Support/`  and got rather stressed but I found the path eventually.

This cataloug is hidden and you have to unhide it with the commando in a terminal window: chflags nohidden `/Users/your username/Library/Application Support/`

Comment: It is **not** necessary to "unhide" the Library directory.  To open a hidden folder in the finder just open a new finder window (Command-N) and then Shift-Command-G, this will bring up a dialog where you can enter the folder path. You can use "~" as a shortcut for "/Users/your username" thus you can just enter: "~/Library/Application Support". Or just enter "wallet.dat" in Spotlight.